# Take values of translate functions in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, translate

I am using circle objects and I need to save translate function values. For example

```
circle3 = container.append("circle")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + 80 + "," + 365 + ")")
.attr("r", 10)
.attr("fill", "gray");

circle2 = container.append("circle")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + 80+ "," + 455+ ")")
.attr("r", 10)
.attr("fill", "gray");
```

Circle objects are in draggable form. How can I register their new translate value(I mean it will be update after dragging) to variable or arrays. Is there any method provide that values?

Thanks,

Comment: It really depends on how you are making them draggable.  If you are are manually dragging them then you can just save the new x and y values, alternatively you can view style.transform and process the returned string, which will be in the format "translate(x,y)".

Comment: How did you make the circles draggable? What do you want to do with the updated position? Please explain further on what you are trying to do.